# Symfony2: Undefined method: getDoctrine()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am very new to Symfony2 and can't seem to wrap my head around this issue. 
When executing an action, I am receiving this error:

```
Call to undefined method: getDoctrine()
```

**Controller:**

```
public function createAction() {

  $string = new FrontendString();
  $string->setStringval("Hayaku!");

  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $em->persist($string);
  $em->flush();

  return new Response('Created string with id '. $string->getId());
}
```

The Entity file has all its generated getters and setters according to correct annotations. I have no Repository or Model folder. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: show declaration of your controller class

Comment: I don't have access to it at the moment, but the only use-statements I used was to include Response and FrontendString. The namespace pointed to the folder of the current file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your controller extends [Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html), read about it [in documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-base-controller-class)

> For convenience, Symfony2 comes with a base Controller class that
>   assists with some of the most common controller tasks and gives your
>   controller class access to any resource it might need. By extending
>   this Controller class, you can take advantage of several helper
>   methods.

Comment: The example I followed from the documentation doesn't do it that way
(http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html, search for Persisting Objects to the Database). I'll try doing it this explicitly, but is it "best practice" or even the right way?

Comment: Quite from [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#persisting-objects-to-the-database): "From inside a controller, this is pretty easy. Add the following method to the DefaultController of the bundle". DefaultController its a part of autogenerated bundle and his extend base symfony controller

Comment: Aw, god darn it. *chuckles*