# how to select all fields in SYMFONY 3.x

Tags: symfony

I select from DB only nameSurname:

```
$em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$users = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.nameSurname FROM MyBundle:User u')
            ->getResult();

var_dump($users); 
exit;
```

But how to select all fields in SYMFONY 3.x like simple sql query?

```
       select * from table
```

UPD that not work, work but show much more and not users information i think

```
$users = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u')
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: With your last code, you'll retrieve all the user entities, with all user fields.

Comment: What does that means "UPD that not work, work but show much more and not users information i think" ? What is displayed is your entity user, may be it extends other thing ? Or your ORM is not well configured.

Comment: Don't user `var_dump` but the symfony `dump()` function (in deb mode)

Answer (score 0):

This should return all your User Entities:

```
$users = $em->createQuery('SELECT u FROM MyBundle:User u')
            ->getResult();
```

Now `$users` contains all the users information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do this way?

to select specific user:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->find($userId);
$userName = $user->getName();
$userEmail = $user->getEmail();
etc...
```

to select all users:

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->findAll();
```

Comment: I extend ContainerAwareCommand and when I use `getDoctrine()` in it , I get error 

>  Attempted to call an undefined method named "getDoctrine" of class ...

MyExampleCommand   extends ContainerAwareCommand

Comment: If I understand getDoctrine() will work if my class extends Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20682611/6250381